# Page_Load Paradigm in Windows Forms?? What is it?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a windows forms application and I have a drop down that is bound to a dataset. Upon load I want to bind the control to the database value. I have some validation that takes place but I only want this to occur after the form has loaded and the user changes a value in the drop down. Currently I have the code in a _SelectedIndexChanged event. This gets fired when the control is also bound to the database value.

I know in asp.net I can say (!Page.IsPostBacK) to control whether or not it should fire the code. What is the windows forms paradigm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be to have a `bool` variable on your form set to `false`. Inside the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, set the variable to `true`. When your validation code executes, have it check that value of the `bool` variable to determine whether the validation should be performed.

Answer (score 0):

**Code :**

```
 public bool ispostbask = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     }
  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ispostbask)
        {
            //your code
        }
        ispostbask = true;
    }
```